# How to create jquery sidebar with fixed header

Tags: jquery, header, scroll, fixed, sidebar

have a look at this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var length = $('#left').height() - $('#sidebar').height() + $('#left').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        var height = $('#sidebar').height() + 'px';
        if (scroll < $('#left').offset().top) {
            $('#sidebar').css({
                'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0'
            });
        } else if (scroll > length) {
            $('#sidebar').css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'bottom': '0',
                'top': 'auto'
            });
        } else {
            $('#sidebar').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': '0',
                'height': height
            });
        }
    });
});
```

this code sets the side bar to fix until reaches a certain position. it works well but problem is I am trying to add a fixed topbar with 40px height, how can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want a bar across the top of the site in addition to this sidebar?

Comment: Could you put pictures here - screenshots of what you got and a draw of what you want. Please.

Comment: a topbar is header with top set to 0, left 0, right 0, fixed position, 100% width, 40px height and so on. just so it stays fixed at the top. And the sidebar just like the related topics on this site.